# Scala: Difference between function declarations

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, below are three function declarations that are confusing to me:

**First**

```
scala> def sum = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int, Int) => Int
```

**Second**

```
scala> def sum (a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int
```

**Third**

```
scala> val sum = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

I know that the second one is method, third one is a function literal. *My confusion is with the first declaration*, is it a normal function or is it a some other syntax that I do not understand? An explanation would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Also, when I try to create a partially applied function using the first declaration I get this:

```
scala> val anotherSum = sum _
anotherSum: () => (Int, Int) => Int = <function0>
```

Which I expected to be of type `Function2` as `sum` has 2 parameters.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_closures.htm . Dig around scala closures ,,

Comment: "I know that the second one is a normal function" – No, the second one is a method, not a function. The first one is also a method (albeit one that returns a function). Only the third one is a function.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and second declarations declare different things. It's not the same thing with different syntax.

```
scala> def sum = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int, Int) => Int
```

Here, you define a method named `sum` that takes no parameters and returns a function that takes two `Int` parameters and returns an `Int`.

So, `sum` is a **method** that **returns a function** that adds two numbers.

```
scala> def sum (a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int
```

Here, you define a method named `sum` that takes two `Int` parameters and that returns an `Int`.

So, `sum` is a **method** that adds two numbers.

The difference is that in the first version, `sum` takes no parameters and returns a function, and in the second, `sum` takes two parameters and returns an `Int`. Two very different things!

The third:

```
scala> val sum = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
sum: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

Here you define a **value** named `sum` that is a `Function2`, in other words, a function that takes two `Int` parameters and returns an `Int`.

So, `sum` is a **value** that is of type `Function2`, and refers to a function that adds two numbers.

Extra:

```
scala> val anotherSum = sum _
anotherSum: () => (Int, Int) => Int = <function0>
```

Look carefully at the type. `anotherSum` is a function that takes no parameters that returns a function that takes two `Int` parameters that returns an `Int`.

You are not partially applying anything here. [Section 6.7 Method Values](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values) of the Scala Language Specification explains what happens here.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation.